# How to connect to MySQL database in silverlight using ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby, silverlight, ironruby

when i use

```
require 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

or

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
```

in app.rb silverlight plugin crashing...

```
include System::Data
```

says

```
MemberAccessException: uninitialized constant System::Data
```

but System.Data.dll includes in xap file

anyone knows how i can connect to mysql database in silverlight using ruby?
P.S. i use ironruby Chiron server to generate *.xap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to setup a direct connection to your MYSQL server using silverlight. I think the trust levels in silverlight prohibit you to load the assemblies. 
What you should do is not using the database directly (why would you expose your database server directly?) and create a small webservice (e.g. MVC app) to handle json requests and interact that way with your data.

Comment: its solution not better than Ajax...and I have to insert new data into silverlight application when they appear in the database. In this case, I have to constantly poll the database, rather RoR Project. in C # and VB, I found a class that Sistem.Data.SqlClient may connect to the database and consequently well with her work, but im use ruby...